# Facing Issue when I upgrade Flutter_Stripe Package Version

Tags: flutter, backend, flutter-dependencies, flutter-stripe

hello now when i click on pay with stripe it is showing error. before updating version it was working fine
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmhLe.jpg)

I/flutter (32337): eccezione'package:flutter_stripe/src/stripe.dart': Failed assertion: line 488 pos 9: '!(paymentSheetParameters.applePay != null &&

I/flutter (32337): instance._merchantIdentifier == null)': merchantIdentifier must be specified if you are using Apple Pay. Please refer to this article to get a merchant identifier: https://support.stripe.com/questions/enable-apple-pay-on-your-stripe-account

[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atA6X.jpg)

Comment: did you check the article and specified a merchantIdentifier?